# How to create an email with sender field populated in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have an `Xpages` view [only used in `XPiNC]` with a list of users. Want to display their email addresses and have the user be able to click the address and open a new email in their email application with `SendTo` populated with the email of the user they clicked on.

I can get a link to work to open a new email.

```
<xp:link escape="true"
    text="New Memo" id="link2"
    value="Notes:///0000000000000E00/Memo?OpenForm">
</xp:link>
```

But in the post I got this the author said there was no way to pre-populate fields.

Is there a simple way to do this, or should I just write `SSJS` to do it, or even worse, run an `LS` agent?

Comment: Over engineering in my opinion, but you can compose the document in a background agent, save it in user's mail file and redirect to notes URL to open it. Deal with already saved but empty and discarded by user documents, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use standard HTML, make the link a `mailto:` link. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Comment: Paul, this keeps opening in my browser, but I want to open the user's mail file.

Comment: That should launch in whatever is the default mail client for the PC. It opens in Notes (or iNotes if I'm using the browser plugin) for me. It sounds like a configuration issue.